# Unity IOS Facebook: FB.Login brings me to an Error Window on the iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, unity-game-engine

After I compiled my game in Unity and XCode, I'm running the game on my iPhone. And when `FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback)` gets called, it brings me to a window that says

```
Error
App not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.
```

In the App Dashboard `Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public`? is set to NO, HOWEVER I've added a Test User in the App Dashboard, and I'm logged in as that Test User on my phone outside of my app under Settings. Shouldn't this work? I don't want to publish my app to all users just yet.

I also double checked:

- "App Id" in Unity -> Facebook -> Edit Settings is the same as the one in the App Dashboard
- "Bundle ID" in the App Dashboard is the same as in Unity's Player Settings -> Bundle Identifier

In the App Dashboard I have "App Domain" empty, since I just run it from the iPhone and not from the Web. Or do I still need an App Domain..?

Not sure if it's relevant, but on running `FB.Init`, he logs this in XCode:

```
Using SDK 4.3.6, Build 131121.17562b74012d24a
Finished loading Facebook dll. Build N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

DO you have Facebook APP id in info.plist?  check bundle id is case sensitive?  Is single sign on set to yes in Facebook dashboard?  also try enabling client auth login and embedded browser auth login in FB dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Everything was set up correctly with the app on Facebook and Unity, however just on my phone my Facebook app had another user logged in.
Seems like that is a different login thing that when you log in under Settings.

Thanks for your help though!